# Mixpanel Push Notification ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, mixpanel

In a Mixpanel Admin,Under Notification,If I Filter a specified device as shown in below link (filter based on Email-> choose one Email to send to the corresponding device user) but 'Your filter returned no matching users'
If I see [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/why-are-users-not-sent-my-notification).I need to add something in People Analytics.As this is a beginning to handle Notification.I have no idea why Its not matching user.

```
 [[Mixpanel sharedInstance] .people set:@{@"Email":[pre objectForKey:@"SignInUserEmailId"]}];
```

This is how I am tract it in Mixpanel People Analytics,Is It Right or anything else I need to do for People Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got an solution for Push Notification,

Under 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken'

Mixpanel *mixpanel = [Mixpanel sharedInstance];

[mixpanel identify:@"123456"];

[mixpanel.people addPushDeviceToken:usertoken];

Thee addPushDeviceToken function will take care of the $union operation. In that example, the "123456" would be an example of the distinct ID you are registering that push token for. If you want to use the current distinct ID on the device, you would do [mixpanel identify:mixpanel.distinctId]

Answer (score 0):

Push Notification with Swift. Put the below code in AppDelegate.swift file

You can receive notifications in the code and on device as well if the app is minimized.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.        

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    //pass the project token from mixpanel account
    let mixpanel = Mixpanel.sharedInstanceWithToken("4e35256cfd95a9b236936bcf0104bb92")

    mixpanel.identify("564") //564 is the unique distinct id of user
    mixpanel.people.set(["name": "your name", "$email": "email@email.com", "Plan": "Free", "$region" : "Australia"])
    mixpanel.people.addPushDeviceToken(deviceToken)        
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    var alert1: String = ""        
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {
                //Do stuff
            }
        } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
            print(alert)
            alert1 = alert as String
        }
    }        
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message:
        alert1, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```